# Scala List and Utility of val and var

Tags: arrays, scala, list

If I am writing

```
val a = 1
```

then it will give me

```
a : Int = 1
```

again if I am writing

```
a = 2
```

It will say reassignment to val and I am fine with this that Ok we cannot reassign the value to a val declared variable in scala.

Now if we come to scala Array in that if we declared variable as val and assign a Scala List of length 3, Then we cannot change the length but we can change the value of individual elements inside that Scala Array. Ok that also make sense because in this case the variable is still immutable but the array internally is mutable.

Now the question is on scala list if I declared a scala list like

```
val OneTwo = List(1,2)
```

will result int he following output:

```
oneTwo: List[Int] = List(1,2)
```

Ok, Now trying this:

```
val OneTwo = List("One","Two")
```

will result int he following output:

```
oneTwo: List[String] = List("One","Two")
```

I don't know why the list variable i.e., oneTwo is mutable that we can reassign it to a new kind of object. Why it is behaving just like the java String where the object become immutable but the variable to which it is assigned can be assigned to a new String object. If it is so then what is the utility of declaring it as a val here.

Comment: are you using REPL for this test??

Comment: try doing oneTwo = List("One", "Two") without prefixing it with a val. You would get the same reassigning to val error.

Comment: you are simply creating a new val with second statement. It is not assigning new value to existing val, instead it is creating a new val named oneTwo.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying this in scala REPL.
You can't reassign a val but you can re-declare it in REPL.

Re-declaration would also work for variable

```
val a = 1  
val a = 2
```

Comment: when we are doing the same that you did it says we cant reassign and I am fine with it. but in case of arrays as in question why it allows to reassign it to a new object